# multiview images points matching for common points

Tags: matlab, 3d, computer-vision, matlab-cvst

Recently, I deal with Multiview 3D reconstruction with Matlab R2013b. Given M images of different view of object with N extracted points with detectSURFFeatures(), how can I match the points together into Multiview match points? So far matchedFeature() can only match two images points together, Is that Matlab able to perform Multiview matching as mention above?
I would likes to ask for some example codes with explanation for Multiview matching mentioned above.

Comment: You can use bundler and pmvs if you're willing to consider other solutions.

Comment: Since I have to do it on Matlab, I have no choice for it...

Answer (score 0):

This [example](http://www.mathworks.com/help/vision/ug/sparse-3-d-reconstruction-from-multiple-views.html) includes a helper function that does the multi-view matching using the [KDTreeSearcher](http://www.mathworks.com/help/stats/kdtreesearcher-class.html) object from the Statistics Toolbox.

Comment: Thanks for info but the helper functions cannot run in R2013b version of Matlab. Please give me other suggestions too for Multiview matching. Thanks.

Comment: In that case, you should consider writing this yourself using the KDTreeSearcher. You put all your descriptors into the KDTreeSearcher, and you do knnsearch for query features. You would also need to keep track of which descriptor comes from which image.

Comment: May I know what is descriptor and how to do knnsearch?

Comment: First you do `detectSURFFeatures'. That gives you keypoints or interest points.  Then you do `extractFeatures`. That gives you the descirptors, also known as feature vectors.  `knnsearch` is a method of class `KDTreeSearcher`. See the link above.